# How does ASP.NET manage server-side variables with many users modifying them at once?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, client-server

What I'm wondering is, what happens when more than 1 user are using a website application developed on ASP.NET and modifying it variables, for example:

UserA sets some data to a server-side variable:

```
var = 5
```

Then, UserB, on a different PC logs on and sets some other data to the same server-side variable:

```
var = 7
```

Then UserA runs a process which needs the value in the var variable, say it's gonna print the value, what would the program print? 5 or 7?

I know client-side variables would only have meaning for the user in question, but I have no idea what's gonna happen with the server-side ones. Thanks!

Comment: are these static variables?

Comment: Just your regular "Dim var as Integer" variables.

Comment: the variables are unique to the session the user is in

Comment: I see, is this done by default? Or is there some setting that needs to be set? Also what would happen if the users didn't have to log in for some areas of the website? Would they still have a session?

Comment: I apologize I should not have used the word session. The variables are unique per user whether they are logged in or not

Comment: @knobcreekman Variables are only session-scoped if they're manually stored... in the session. What the OP probably needs to become more familiar with is the ASP.NET Request / Response pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Asp.net application life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For each request from the user a object of the page requested is created.
Each request has its own copy of such inner variables and so other users will not be able to see them.

Note that such variables are only present for the request. If you have buttons on the page and the user comes back, these will again set reset to their original values during the [Page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you want variables to maintain their state for each user, you should keep them in the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.page.session.aspx) or [`ViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms972976.aspx).

Variables kept in the `Session` collection are maintained across pages, while those in the `ViewState` are retained till you are on the same page. Both collections have their merits and drawbacks. You must understand them well to decide which is the right place to store the variables.

Comment: I think I understand this, so every time a user chose to start a process, an object of the class would be instantiated, thus creating the same set of variables for each of the objects that were requested, and even if a variable changed its value, it wouldn't matter to the other identical variables since they are independent because they only exist in their respective objects.